# JQuery: Retrieve and update SINGLE span value inside a (wordpress) loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom

I've been struggling with this for two days, obviously because I have a very little knowledge in jQuery / Javascript, and I think I've searched thoroughly for so many times but didn't get the answer that I need.

I'm working with a Wordpress loop, each loop item has: a span with a class, and a link to trigger an update via jQuery to that span's value / content.

What I have by far is: when I click a trigger-link - let's say on the first loop-item, ALL of the span's value / content on ALL of item loop is updated. What I'm trying to achieve is as simple as: when I click a trigger-link on the first loop-item, it update the span's value / content on that loop-item only.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="loop-item>
 <span class="count">123</span>
 <span><a class="update"></a></span>
 <p>some text</p>
</div>

<div class="loop-item>
 <span class="count">123</span>
 <span><a class="update"></a></span>
 <p>some text</p>
</div>

<div class="loop-item>
 <span class="count">123</span>
 <span><a class="update"></a></span>
 <p>some text</p>
</div>

<div class="loop-item>
 <span class="count">123</span>
 <span><a class="update"></a></span>
 <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".update").click(function(){
  var countVal = $(".count").text();
  var nuVal = countVal + 1;
  $(".count").text(nuVal);
 });
});
```

I know it's an entirely wrong jQuery code. I'm willing to learn and hoping someone here is willing to help to get it right.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The working jQuery codes are as follow (modified the nuVal variable):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".update").click(function(){
  var countSpan = $(this).closest(".loop-item").find(".count");
  var countVal = countSpan.text();
  var nuVal = parseInt(countVal) + 1;
  countSpan.text(nuVal);
 });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one is easy enough, i see two main issues first what you are saying here is:

```
$(".count").text(nuVal);
```

is changing all items with the class count.

second your loop item divs are missing a quote at the end of the class:

```
<div class="loop-item>
```

if i understand correctly you are looking to accomplish this: on click of a link element with class "update" change the value of only the span element of class "count" within that same loop-item div.

here is how we can accomplish that task:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".update").click(function(){
  // get the container of class .loop-item and grab the span element of class count
  // and store that element in the countSpan variable
  var countSpan = $(this).closest(".loop-item").find(".count");

  var countVal = countSpan.text();
  var nuVal = countVal + 1;
  countSpan.text(nuVal);
 });
});
```

Comment: This one works, although the nuVal variable which is meant as an addition math didn't work. I modified it to:

var nuVal = parseInt(countVal)+1;

and it works! Thank you so much! ps: yes, the <div class="loop-item> was a typo, as I was re-typing the whole code here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the click() callback, `$this` will refer to the `<span class="update">`. So you can select its grandparent as a base to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".update").click(function(){
  var base = $(this).parent().parent(); //loop-item
  var nuVal = base.find(".count").text() + 1;
  base.find(".count").text(nuVal);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".update").click(function(){
      var parent = $(this).parent('span').parent('div');
      var countVal = $(".count", parent).text();
      var nuVal = countVal + 1;
      $(".count", parent).text(nuVal);
   });
});
```

You basically need to grab the parent of the item you have clicked and use that to select the inline elements you need.